# How to delete login accounts from Salesforce1 Android mobile app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, android

As a consultant/developer, I use the mobile app to log in to lots of different orgs. The list of login accounts grows and grows.

How can I delete such a login account from that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete login accounts by logging out.

Comment: Works for iOS as well (as a colleague of mine verified with his iPhone)